# Office 2013 doesn't create owner files

Tags: microsoft-word, permissions, microsoft-office

I'm surprised nobody else had this problem yet. When editing files in the Documents user folder a "~$"-file is created. According to [Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/211632/description-of-how-word-creates-temporary-files) it prevents multiple users from editing the file at the same time.

In any other folder however the file is not created, including a cloud-synced folder that is used by multiple people. How do I force Office-Applications such as Word, Excel etc. to write the owner file every time in every folder?

Me and every other user is using Office 2013 and Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

The file should still be created.

The trouble is that it is considered a protected operating system file when it's not in your Documents folder.

While in a different folder with a word document, Go to the View (tab) -> Options (button) -> Change Folder and Search options

[image]

Select the View tab, and untick this option (Hide protected operating system files):

[image]

Now open a document in that folder, you should see the ~$ file being created.

Even without this option set though, if someone else opens that file (even though they can't see the ~$ file) MS Office should notify them that it is currently in use.